# MediaCapture Initialize failing even after adding in Manifest and providing permissions

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to capture image using the camera available in the device.

I tried the sample camera app provided by Microsoft (https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit)

This sample app has Webcamera and microphone access applied in manifest. When the app starts, permissions are even provided but still I get exception saying access denied.

```
_mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();

var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings { VideoDeviceId = cameraDevice.Id };

try
{
   await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings); //Getting exception here
   _isInitialized = true;
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
{
   Debug.WriteLine("The app was denied access to the camera");
}
```

In Package.appxmanifest

```
...
<Capabilities>
   <uap:Capability Name="picturesLibrary" />
   <DeviceCapability Name="webcam" />
   <DeviceCapability Name="microphone" />
</Capabilities>
...
```

[image]

Enabled access for the app too.

I have checked the camera app permissions too. Still I get access denied exception in _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings).

This same app is working fine in other machines.

Comment: The problem may  occur in the camera device, please try to replace other camera test.

Comment: Camera works fine if I use it in other apps.

Comment: Please check if you have switch off the capability in the *Camera Privacy Setting*

Comment: Enabled capability for the app.

Comment: Updated my screenshot too. The option is enabled.

Comment: Have you tried to re-install this app?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199249/discussion-between-ram-kishore-and-nico-zhu-msft).

Comment: If you are working in a cooperation network. The camera could be managed by the network policy. Does the policy disable the camera?